# Refused a Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, paperwork, visa-refusals

I was refused a Schengen visa to Germany.

I used to work at first but along the way I stopped work and went to school; I just finished my national service but still have not graduated yet because of one paper I have to go and write. Due to being in school, I could not save any more in my bank account, and due to that I personally could not issue my bank statement for the trip.

The man inviting me sent all his documents to the local embassy in Germany before, and he was given this paper (*Verpflicthungserklärung*) which proves when I am there he can sponsor me very well. Also submitted were my proof of my service attestation and my application, and my uncle's bank statement and company certificate. But with all this, I was still denied the visa.

So what must I do now, as my friend is waiting for my arrival?

Comment: Which boxes were checked? And your nationality?

Comment: @pnuts There's no such reason.  The OP needs to say what reasons they actually gave.

Comment: @pnuts, I meant that 'lack of bank statement' is not a reason they give for refusals. It's nowhere in the refusal formulae.

Comment: @pnuts, AH! I see your point.  It's possibly innocent vandalism by a well-intended editor.

Comment: After the coherent edit... Araba, what boxes were checked AND was the Verpflichtungserklärung registered?

Comment: What was the purpose of your visit?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the solution is to get a new job. (Or maybe enroll in university in your home country). Maybe get married and start a family.  But do something to show that you have ties to your home country, and have every intention of returning.

The way your application looks, you are "between jobs." For all they know, you might be looking for a new one in Germany. That's a scenario they don't want to deal with.

Comment: But there was a Verpflichtungserklärung.  Possibly dodgy...